# usort error in php 5.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am newbi in PHP developer

I try to sort with this help http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#103722

```
function usortByArrayKey($key, $asc=SORT_ASC) {
$sort_flags = array(SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC);

if (!in_array($asc, $sort_flags))
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('sort flag only accepts SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC');

return function(array $a, array $b) use ($key, $asc, $sort_flags) {
            if (!is_array($key)) { //just one key and sort direction
                if (!isset($a[$key]) || !isset($b[$key])) {
                    throw new Exception('attempting to sort on non-existent keys');
                }
                if ($a[$key] == $b[$key])
                    return 0;
                return ($asc == SORT_ASC xor $a[$key] < $b[$key]) ? 1 : -1;
            } else { //using multiple keys for sort and sub-sort
                foreach ($key as $sub_key => $sub_asc) {
                    //array can come as 'sort_key'=>SORT_ASC|SORT_DESC or just 'sort_key', so need to detect which
                    if (!in_array($sub_asc, $sort_flags)) {
                        $sub_key = $sub_asc;
                        $sub_asc = $asc;
                    }
                    //just like above, except 'continue' in place of return 0
                    if (!isset($a[$sub_key]) || !isset($b[$sub_key])) {
                        throw new Exception('attempting to sort on non-existent keys');
                    }
                    if ($a[$sub_key] == $b[$sub_key])
                        continue;
                    return ($sub_asc == SORT_ASC xor $a[$sub_key] < $b[$sub_key]) ? 1 : -1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        };
```

}

the problems is, I am using PHP 5.2
then I change the code like this

```
function usortByArrayKey(&$array, $key, $asc=SORT_ASC) { 
    $sort_flags = array(SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC); 
    if(!in_array($asc, $sort_flags)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('sort flag only accepts SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC'); 
    }
    $cmp = $this->_usortByArrayKey($key, $asc, $sort_flags); 
    usort($array, $cmp); 
    //return $array;
}

function _usortByArrayKey($key, $asc=SORT_ASC, array $sort_flags, array $a, array $b){ 
    if(!is_array($key)) { //just one key and sort direction 
        if(!isset($a[$key]) || !isset($b[$key])) { 
            throw new Exception('attempting to sort on non-existent keys'); 
        } 
        if($a[$key] == $b[$key]) {
            return 0; 
        }
        return ($asc==SORT_ASC xor $a[$key] < $b[$key]) ? 1 : -1; 
    } else { //using multiple keys for sort and sub-sort 
        foreach($key as $sub_key => $sub_asc) { 
            //array can come as 'sort_key'=>SORT_ASC|SORT_DESC or just 'sort_key', so need to detect which 
            if(!in_array($sub_asc, $sort_flags)) 
            { 
                $sub_key = $sub_asc; $sub_asc = $asc; 
            } 
            //just like above, except 'continue' in place of return 0 
            if(!isset($a[$sub_key]) || !isset($b[$sub_key])) { 
                throw new Exception('attempting to sort on non-existent keys'); 
            } 
            if($a[$sub_key] == $b[$sub_key]) {
                continue; 
            }
            return ($sub_asc==SORT_ASC xor $a[$sub_key] < $b[$sub_key]) ? 1 : -1; 
        } 
        return 0; 
    } 
}
```

but I am still get the error

error :

```
Message: Argument 4 passed to ConnectList::_usortByArrayKey() must be an array, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\receiverlist\application\models\connect.php on line 321 and defined
Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'attempting to sort on non-existent keys'
```

Comment: The link you give looks broken (which note has the code you have)? It looks like it has been replaced with a new version.

Answer (score 3):

In codeigniter to enter a callabck function into a PHP function is needs to be something like:

```
usort($array, array('name-of-controller', 'name-of-method'));
```

Obviously replacing the names where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

you're writing this:
`$cmp = $this->_usortByArrayKey($key, $asc, $sort_flags);`
but your function `_usortByArrayKey` accepts 5 required parameters, and you passing only 3. Tha'ts why the 1st message `Message: Argument 4 passed to ConnectList::_usortByArrayKey() must be an array, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\receiverlist\application\models\connect.php on line 321 and defined`
 appears

Answer (score 0):

The problem you ask about is that you need to convert an anonymous function which is not available in PHP 5.2 into a something that works with PHP 5.2. The function head:

```
function(array $a, array $b) use ($key, $asc, $sort_flags)
```

As this is making use of the `use` clause, you will need to mimic this with a class in PHP 5.2. Simplified example for:

```
function ($a) use ($b)
```

A class can go like this:

```
class Func
{
    private $b;
    public function __construct($b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function invoke($a) {
        $b = $this->b; # operate on $b, not $this->b
    }
    public function getCallback() {
        return array($this, 'invoke');
    }
}
```

How does this work? Usage Example:

```
$func = new Func($b);
return $func->getCallback();
```

What is the pattern?

1. You create a new class that represents the function.
2. Variables from the `use` clause are constructor parameters.
3. You create a `invoke` function that represents the function.
4. Inside the `invoke` function all use-variables are copied into the local scope.
5. a `getCallback()` function provides the callback you can use to call the function.